# Automatic deserialize child nodes when using AnnotationStrategy

Tags: java, converters, simple-framework

I am working with SimpleXML library for Java. Currently, I am trying to deserialize node using @Convert annotation. I override the read() method in Converter interface, which has following prototype:

`Converter.read(InputNode node)`

In the read() method, I iterate child nodes and deserialize them. However, some of subnodes are quite complex and I would like them to deserialize normal way, using current context. I think it may be done using Traverser class:

```
public void read(InputNode node) {
    InputNode child;
    while ((child = node.getNext()) != null) {
        String name = child.getName();
        if (name == "child1") {
            //manually read object - no problem
            MyFirstClass object = new MyFirstClass(child.getValue());
        } else if (name == "child2") {
            //automatically read object - here is the problem
            Traverser traverser = new Traverser(context);
            MySecondClass object = traverser.read(child, MySecondClass.class);
        }
    }
}
```

There are two problems with that:

1. Traverser class is internal class of SimpleXML, and in default, it is not available outside.
2. I do not have access to context object in read method. InputNode does not provide a way to access it.

Is there any way to acquire Context object in this place without complex modification of SimpleXML? Changing visibility of Traverser class is easy, but providing context is not.

Or maybe, is there any easier way to do what I need?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the Persister you created and instead of using AnnotationStrategy use RegistryStrategy.